# How to run sagemath file in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, math, pip, ubuntu-18.04, sage

I want to run a `.sagews` file in `python3`

I have installed the `sage-0.0.0` package on `Ubuntu 18.04`

[pip3 install sage](https://pypi.org/project/sage/#files)

```
...
...
Successfully built sage

Installing collected packages: sage

Successfully installed sage-0.0.0
```

according to the [source](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/8782/how-do-i-convert-a-notebook-to-a-python-script/)

*I wrote the code on the point.py file:*

```
from sage.all import *

p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
F = GF(p)
E = EllipticCurve(F, [0,7])
E.count_points(2)
```

*I run in the terminal:*

```
sage -python3 point.py
```

*and I get a warning*

```
/bin/bash: sage: command not found
```

*I run in the terminal:*

```
python3 point.py
```

*and*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "point.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sage.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.all'
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? How can you run the `sage` file using `python3`?

Comment: Have you tried just running python3 point.py? "sage" is a module and not a standalone command right?

Comment: @Eric Lee
 Unfortunately I am getting the error:      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "point.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sage.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sage.all'

Comment: As far as I know, the PyPI Sage package is unmaintained and outdated; since it is dated 2018, it likely only supports Python 2. You could try to install Sage via conda or by downloading the appropriate file from https://www.sagemath.org/download-linux.html.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Thank you